# What is the planned date for the Falcon Heavy Demo launch from Vandenberg AFB?

Tags: launch, rockets, spacex, observation, falcon-heavy

According to Wikipedia and SpaceX, this demo flight is scheduled for 2014.  A group of us from San Diego want to come and watch the launch from a distance.  Is there any scheduled date for the launch?  If there's no specific date planned yet, what's the best resource/website to check to keep up with any news?

Thanks!

Comment: I think Falcon Heavy test flight is scheduled for 2015: http://nextbigfuture.com/2014/03/spacex-falcon-heavy-launch-delayed-to.html

Comment: Many groups schedule launches as 'NET' (No Earlier Than) ... even for test flights, there might be a designated time period, as there can be competition for the launch facilities from missions with specific launch windows.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rocket launches are notorious for not making deadlines. Especially the first launch of a new type (ISS launches, interestingly enough, have a very narrow window, usually a minute or three, so they eventually get to the point where they can launch on time).

Therefore any date given today, for a date in the future is utterly meaningless.

SpaceX will undoubtedly make a BIG deal about a Falcon Heavy initial launch. Of course, you will be able to check the [SpaceX](http://www.spacex.com/) home page.

Generally, the most reliable source for launch info that I have found is at SpaceFlight Now's [launch tracking page](http://spaceflightnow.com/launch-schedule/). Which as of this writing, does not even have a date listed for a Falcon Heavy launch.

**Update:** The SpaceFlight Now page, as of January 4th 2017, lists a "2nd Quarter 2017" launch for the Falcon Heavy Demo.

**Update2:** As of Jan 2018, the launch is expected any day now, as a Wet Dress Rehersal has completed, but a Static Fire is still pending.

Additionally first launch will be from Florida at pad LC-39A no longer at Vandenberg.

Comment: I second spaceflightnow.com as an excellent source.  Especially as the launch gets closer.

Comment: Instaneous launch is more the exception than the norm for the ISS

Comment: in other way,  Delayed from 3rd Quarter of 2015 and April, September and December 2016. Delayed from 1st Quarter 2017, 2nd Quarter 2017 and 3rd Quarter 2017. Delayed from November and December 2017

Answer (score 9):

SpaceX has in particular been notorious about delaying their recent flights. The advent of the Falcon 9 v1.1 was about a year late, as you can see from looking at some of the mission dates in the history on SpaceFlight Now. For instance, the upcoming CRS mission shows that the following have been listed as it's launch date:

> April 6, Sept. 30, Nov. 11, Dec. 9, Jan. 15, Feb. 11, Feb. 22, March 1 and March 16. [March 14]

SpaceFlightNow is a fantastic resource, even many in the industry use it to keep track of things.

As for the launch of the Falcon 9 heavy, I wouldn't put any serious money towards watching it happening until it's a month away. Even then, don't be surprised if it doesn't launch for a few weeks after the scheduled date. Stuff happens in the space industry.